# IE9 Overflow hidden issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, overflow

I'm having an issue in IE9 (at least, haven't checked the other IE's) where a div with `overflow:hidden` is being ignored by it's child div. The blue outlined div in the image is the `overflow:hidden` container div. The images should be contained within the container.

I know that setting the container div to `position:relative` will work but there are absolutely positioned "previous" and "next" buttons that won't display if I do that.

This displays fine in Firefox and Chrome

**Actual**
[image: Actual]

**Expected**
[image: Expected]

html

```
<div id="instagramViewer" class="slideshow">
    <div class="slideshowButton" id="prevImage" style="display: block;">
        <a href="#" title="Previous">Previous</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshowButton" id="nextImage">
        <a href="#" title="Next">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="contentItem>
        <span class="contentItem" style="display: block;">
            <a href="javascript: void(0);">
                <img alt="words" src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
            </a>
            <div class="detailsWrapper" style="display: none; opacity: 0.678511;">...</div>
        </span>
        <span class="contentItem" style="display: block;">
            <a href="javascript: void(0);">
                <img alt="words" src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
            </a>
            <div class="detailsWrapper" style="display: none; opacity: 0.678511;">...</div>
        </span>
        <span class="contentItem" style="display: block;">
            <a href="javascript: void(0);">
                <img alt="words" src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
            </a>
            <div class="detailsWrapper" style="display: none; opacity: 0.678511;">...</div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.instagramViewerWrapper .slideshow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.instagramViewerWrapper .slideshow .content {
    margin-left: 256px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.instagramViewerWrapper .slideshow .content .contentItem {
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin: 0 14px 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.instagramViewerWrapper .slideshow .slideshowButton {
    margin-top: 20%;
    position: absolute;
}
.instagramViewerWrapper .slideshow #prevImage {
    left: -75px;
}
.instagramViewerWrapper .slideshow #nextImage {
    right: -75px;
}
```

Comment: I have a couple of ideas. 

 1. Try changing the display style of your content items to inline-block.
 2. Try changing the container positioning to relative - this is necessary in order to tell the browser about the rendering hierarchy. Unfortunately you may have to redesign your prev and next buttons. Maybe you could make the body position relative or add relative positioning to whatever element contains them.

Comment: @Kryptonite based off your comment I ended up redesigning my html so that `div.content` has a parent `div.contentWrapper`. The wrapper has `position: relative; overflow: hidden;`. If you post your comment as an answer I'll give you the credit. Thanks again :)

Comment: Done :) Glad to hear it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a couple of ideas.

1. Try changing the display style of your content items to
   inline-block.
2. Try wrapping the content of the slideshow in a relatively positioned div - this tells the browser about the rendering order of the descendants.  (You will need to recalculate the positioning of your prev and next buttons. In fact, they no longer need to be positioned absolutely - they could be outside the wrapper, floated left and right. Alternatively you could absolutely position them relative to the body. It's up to you.)

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `position:relative` to the elem that is `overflow:hidden` so in you css right below overflow add position relative. I've had this issue in IE before and that fixed it.

Comment: Thank you.! I was having similar issue and resolved by adding `position:relative`.